# NA/too many rows kept in dataframe after merge

Tags: r, merge, r-markdown

I'm trying to merge rows from a dataframe which have a certain value for a column that represents a variable. In this case the variable is called "MORTC", with the values 1, 2, 3 and 4. The rows that are found are put in a new dataframe.

I have tried merging these, however the resulting dataframe contains a lot of rows which are not applicaple. In my dataset there is only 1 row which contains a value for MORTC (which is 4), and all the other rows don't contain a value for this variable.

Even so, I still get 38 rows, 37 of which contain NA in every column and the result should be only the one row which has the value 4 for MORTC. I don't have this problem when I use different variables/columns

The function I use for the merging of the rows is the following:

```
reduceDataset <- function(Variablelist, ValueList, table){
  Variables <- strsplit(Variablelist, "\\&|\\|")
  Values <- strsplit(ValueList, "\\&|\\|")
  newdf <- NULL

  for(j in 1:(stri_count_regex(Variablelist, "\\&|\\|")+1)){

  #if the collection of variables is the first in the list of variables
   if(j == 1){      
     newdf <- table[table[sapply(Variables, "[", j)] == sapply(Values, "[", j),]
     j <- 2
  }  


     subdf <- table[which(table[sapply(Variables, "[", j)] == sapply(Values, "[", j)),]

     if(grepl("\\|", Variablelist)){         
        newdf <- merge(newdf, subdf, all=TRUE)
     }
     else{
       newdf <- merge(newdf, subdf)
     }

  }

  return(newdf)
}
```

the input for variablelist is "MORTC|MORTC|MORTC|MORTC"

the input for ValueList is "1|2|3|4"

If anyone can explain why all the extra rows are also added while other variables haven't given me this problem I would be very grateful

Comment: when `merge(newdf, subdf, all=TRUE)` is executed it keeps all the data in both the dataframes `newdf` and `subdf`. Also both dataframes should have something common to merge from, one column should be named the same if you aren't providing them explicitly. However, without data, it is impossible to tell. Could you put `dput` of `newdf` and `subdf` here?

Comment: I have tried to make a file and print the dataframes. I didn't succeed in using dput, but I was able to print a part of the data frame:


3327      NA    NA   NA

3328      NA    NA   NA

3329      NA    NA   NA

In total there are 69343958 rows (all NA).
The script I have used as example is:

Comment: df <- data.frame(matrix("", ncol=3, nrow = 38))
    colnames(df) <- c("Var1", "MORTC", "Var3")

    df[1,2] <- 4
    df[,1] <-  c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
    df[,3] <- c(3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,1,3)

    varlist <- c("MORTC|MORTC|MORTC|MORTC")
    vallist <- c("1|2|3|4")

    resultdf <- reduceDataset(varlist, vallist, df)